# How to display an image using raw controller?

Tags: magento2, controllers

I'm new to magento and learning hard thesedays.
I have a task to display an image using raw controller but couldn't really find out how to do this.
I have my image on etc/frontend/web/images as shown on the screenshot.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMNmW.png

and my raw controller code is as below.

'''

class Raw extends Action
{
protected $raw;

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Raw $raw
){
    $this->raw = $raw;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->raw->create();
    $result->render('<img src="../etc/frontend/web/images/Japan_bg.png"/>');
    return $result;
}
```

}

'''

I know this code is really bad... I have found a way to print image URL but display...
is there anyone who can help me out with this please?

Many thanks!!

Comment: You can use template to display image, learn how to display a simple block/template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display your images in the model of magento.
You can refer to this article: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html